# How can I customize the output format of the \citedate command?

Tags: biblatex

I have the following entry in my .bib file:

```
@article{my_entry,
  author = {{my_author}},
  title = {my_title},
  url = {https://my_url.com},
  urldate = {2024-01-30},
  date = {2019-08-26}
}
```

In my preamble, I'm importing the LaTeX package as follows:

`\usepackage[natbib, backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}`

I also have the babel package imported in Spanish:

`\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}`

The issue is that when I try to cite the date with `\citedate{my_entry}`, the text is displayed as follows:

> 2019, 26 de agosto

But I would like it to be displayed as:

> 26 de agosto de 2019

How could I achieve this?